# Toggle transistors with an shiftregister to light up an LED

Tags: transistors, resistors, shift-register

First of all I'm quit new to electrical engineering. I had it 3 years in class but I didn't do well.

So here is what I plan. I got some shift-registers (74HC595) Which I'll set with an arduino mega 2560. With this I'd like to light up an LED. First I thought I could do it without any other circuit by just adding the right resistor to the 5V lane of the register.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOND4f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I noticed that the register can handle up to 700mW so it wouldn't be possible and I think that the idea overall is bad. So I decided to add transistors to the circuit.(2N3904)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCPhGk.png)</sup>

So my question is, if I need a resistor in front of the Base of the transistor? If so what value or let me know how to calculate it so I can answer it myself for the secont transistor. (see second question down here)

And I got one more question to it. I'd also like to disable LED's by disabling the mass with an transistor. Can I just do it as shown above?

*(To mention this here. I'll use it to light up 75LEDs (25RGB) in 5 Layers. By disabling the mass of a layer I can set one layer of leds at once. This will be mulitplexed to handle each led)*

---

Update: So in total it should be something like this to handle more then one LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ24fv.png)</sup>

---

Since i got kathod LEDs it should need to be like this:

[image: schematic]

Calculation should be simmelar right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your RGB LEDs are common anode, you will need 5 PNP transistors for level control and 75 NPN transistors for LED control.

For PNP it has to handle maximum 75 LEDs and for NPN it has to handle maximum 5 LEDs.
For PNP I recommend using Darlington transistors.

To saturate PNP, \$V_B<V_E\$ and \$V_B<V_C\$. And to saturate NPN, \$V_B>V_E\$ and \$V_B>V_C\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDA1mW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In saturation region, transistor amplifies base current, so there is no need to pass high current to base-emitter. Thus, you can use base resistor. In fact, you *should*, because of current limit of shift register and transistor.

For minimum base resistor value:

$$R_{R2}=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{Q1_{be}}}{(V_{CC}-V_{Q1_{ce}}-V_{D1}-V_{Q2_{ce}})/R_{R1}/h_{fe}*2*75}$$
$$R_{R3}=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{Q2_{be}}}{(V_{CC}-V_{Q1_{ce}}-V_{D1}-V_{Q2_{ce}})/R_{R1}/h_{fe}*2*5}$$

Refer to transistor's datasheet for \$V_{be}\$(Base−Emitter Saturation Voltage), \$V_{ce}\$(Collector−Emitter Saturation Voltage), \$h_{fe}\$(DC Current Gain).
(There may be voltage drop in shift register, but it's not significant, so I omitted it from calculation.)

To be safe, use minimum \$h_{fe}\$ and maximum \$V_{be}~and~V_{ce}\$.

Also, there is high-power shift register. You might want to consider it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I'll have more than one led at a the same line I need to be able to disable them separate. So I have 5 LEDs on QA but just d1 can light up. I'll demultiplex them like this so I can handle the 125rgb LEDs in 5 steps.(5x5x5 rgb led cube) I am sorry that this was unclear. could you give an example for the calculation? Vcc will be 5v and Vbe would be 5V without a resistor.

Comment: I'd be thankful to see one example calculation for exactly the R2. Do I take the Vbe sat and Vce sat values? Which Hfe do I tske there are more than one at the sheet.

Comment: I thinks you mean multiplexing. Multiplexing is getting multiple output from less output, while demultiplexing is getting less input from multiple input. You have to consider every situation, and since it's 'minimum' base resistor value, it will be minimum @all diodes turned on. WIP

Comment: Yes you Are Right i mean multiplexing. Thanks for the correcting.

Comment: What multiplexing method(how many shift register) are you going to use?

Comment: There will be 10 Register in series. Ill push 80 bits in. 5 for the level of the cube and 75 for the 25 RGB LEDs of one level. The levels will be mulitplexed at around 8kHz. To get different colours ill use some kind of pushing 5 bit through an LED color. If there are 5 times 1 it will be at 100% if there are 10100  its around 40%. Thats how ill mix colours. (Ill shift out at 8MHz)BtW i updated the question to clearify what i try todo.

Comment: If you are using 10 registers, you don't need multiplexing, since they have 80 outputs while you have to control 75 LEDs(25 RGB LEDs).

Comment: yes i will control 25rgb LEDs at once(75 single pins). But i got 125 in total. 25rgb at level 1, 25rgb at level 2 and so on till level 5(its a cube of 5x5x5 RGB leds). Each level is connected to the 75 color pins. And the last 5 pins of the 10 register are for enableing the level since i want to be able to controll each level seperat. So i enable level 1 and set the colors for level one. Disable level 1 enable level 2 set colors level 2. This really fast so you cant see that one level is "off".

Comment: I apologize for my poor understanding. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No problem! Thanks alot that you take your time to answer my questions. I dont think that it is that easy.

Comment: uhm I need to say that i have Kathod LED's. So everything would need to be the different way. 5mm RGB kathod(-), U=2,2V/3,3V/3,4V I = 20mA. Going to use 84 and 120 resistor if i remember that right. And i thought about a Mosfet for the Level since they are cheapere than a bipolar one. I guess i got how todo it just need to get the calculations for the resistors right.

Comment: And i think there is one misstake R_{R3} does not need the *5 at the end since there is always just 1 active LED at once at each transistor. Just the R_{R2} does need the *75 since there are 75 active led at one of those. (25RGB) In the end i did not find any highpower shiftregister which does not "drain". Thanks for the help and the time!